# Better way to speed up Binding dropdown list on another dropdown-list onchange in MVC 4 razor

Tags: c#, json, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Change function of a dropdown list **listDeptID** is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {  
       $('#listDeptID').change(function () {
           var selectedDepartmentId = $(this).val();

           $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCities")', { departmentId: selectedDepartmentId }, function (items) {
               var citiesSelect = $('#listcityID');

            citiesSelect.empty();
            $.each(items, function (index, city) {

                citiesSelect.append(
                    $('<option/>')
                        .attr('value', city.cityId)
                        .text(city.cityName)
                );
            });
        });
    });         
});
```

this already working fine.. But its takes some time to bind. 
**items** is Ienumerable object converted as JSON object. I think the looping takes time.
Is there any other method to do the same ?